# Remote Control iPhone device without Jailbreaking the device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, iphone-privateapi

I am working on enterprise application which will allow the desktop to control iPhone devices. Basically so far i am able to display the iPhone screen in the desktop screen using private framework. But i am stuck in sending events to the iPhone. I am getting x and y points but fails to simulate touch event in `iOS 7`. As touch event is possible in `iOS 6` and below with using `GSEvent` private Framework. Also i have used `iOHID` events in iOS 7.1 but it is not working on device. Does IOHID work on non-jailbreak devices?. Please help me.

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19093619/119114) ... but not a duplicate.

Comment: @iOS Dev what do you find concerning this topic plz,have u got a solution?

Comment: @iOS Dev can you please contact, skype name:    live:.cid.2b66f62956c82daa